# Android Studio not generating Appengine Cloud Endpoints for JDO Entities

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, jdo

I have performed following steps:

1. Installed Android Studio 1.5.0.
2. Created a JDO annotated PersistenceCapable Class
3. Right clicked to Generate Google Cloud Endpoint Class.

The generated class is a plain vanilla endpoint without any JDO hooks.

It appears that Android Studio generates correct Google Cloud Endpoints only for Objectify annotated classes.

Can someone confirm if it is possible and if so, how to create endpoints for JDO classes using Android Studio?

Comment: Posting some of your code might be helpful, also describing how you're attempting to generate. Are you using an Android Studio feature, is it automatic, is it based on an SDK command?

Comment: Android Studio only generates specialized code for objectify entities, if you want to use JDO you have implement the methods manually.

Comment: Thanks @loosebazooka.. So if I want to start with Google Datastore for proof of concept for my app and move to Cloud SQL - I simply can't do it because Google doesn't play nice.

Comment: I don't know if you can say that. You can still use JDO, it's just not autogenerated. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries